# I want to accept parameter from url in django rest framework and save it in model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Creating a role based application using django rest framework.
I want to add user based on their roles.I am getting role from url

```
path("create-profile/<str:role>",views.create_profile),
```

I want to add this role to groups field.

```
def create_profile(request,role):
   serializer = CreateProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
   serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
   serializer.save(parent_id = request.user.username)
   return Response("Profile Created Successfully.")
```

If I am trying to use below code before or after serializer.save()

```
serializer.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name = role))
```

Its giving me below error

```
AttributeError: 'CreateProfileSerializer' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

I have also tried to pass keyword argument as I did for parent_id it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Django group based on the role param passed through URL, try:

> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
> role_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=role)
> ```

If you want to add a user to this group, you just created, try:

> ```
> role_group.user_set.add(user)
>             OR
> user.groups.add(role_group)
> ```

If you want to get the param from url and save it in model, you just need to add the field in the model,
extract the param from url and add it into the request body as,

> request.data['role'] = self.kwargs['role']

and save it into the model using the serializer.

Comment: I have already tried using your method.This isn't working.

Comment: Hi @RamshaBukhari I Got the Solution...Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0):

This will add role to "groups" field as "groups" field is an list that's why I used append method to add the role.

```
def create_profile(request,role):
   serializer = CreateProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
   serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
   serializer.validated_data["groups"].append(Group.objects.get(name = role)
   serializer.save(parent_id = request.user.username)
   return Response("Profile Created Successfully.")
```